# ValueError: I/O operation on closed file и RSA

Tags: python, python-2.x, python-2.7, rsa

Такой вот код:

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Cipher import AES, PKCS1_OAEP
import os


disks = []
tmp = []
appdata = os.environ['appdata']
appdata += r'\\'
code = 'somerandomkey'

def GetDisk():
    for x in ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X']:
        try:    
            path = x + ":\\"
            os.chdir(path)
            retval = os.getcwd()
            disks.append(retval)
        except WindowsError:
            continue

def GetDirectory(path):
    for rootdir, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
            for file in files:
                if((file.decode('cp1251').split('.')[-1]) in ['txt','log','avi']):
                    sek = os.path.join(rootdir, file)
                    tmp.append(sek)

def decrypt(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as fobj:
        private_key = RSA.import_key(
        open(appdata + 'prk.bin').read(),
        passphrase=code
    )

    enc_session_key, nonce, tag, ciphertext = [
        fobj.read(x) for x in (private_key.size_in_bytes(), 16, 16, -1)
    ]

    cipher_rsa = PKCS1_OAEP.new(private_key)
    session_key = cipher_rsa.decrypt(enc_session_key)

    cipher_aes = AES.new(session_key, AES.MODE_EAX, nonce)
    data = cipher_aes.decrypt_and_verify(ciphertext, tag)

    handle = open(filename,'wb')
    handle.write(data)

GetDisk()

for d in disks:
    GetDirectory(d)

for filename in tmp:
    try:
        decrypt(filename)
    except IOError:
        continue

print 'done'
```

Я зашифровал свои файлы через RSA алгоритм. prk.bin <- это мой приватный ключ.
Этот код расшифровывает файлы, но я получаю такую ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dectypt.py", line 56, in <module>
    decrypt(filename)
  File "dectypt.py", line 37, in decrypt
    fobj.read(x) for x in (private_key.size_in_bytes(), 16, 16, -1)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

Как это можно пофиксить?

Comment: После выхода из блока `with` контекстный менеджер закрывает файл, а несколькими строками ниже вы пытаетесь из него читать - `fobj.read(x)`.

Comment: То есть надо перенести fobj.read(x) в блок with ?

Comment: Да. Кроме того, ниже у вас файл открывается на запись, но не закрывается. Не надо так. Либо закройте его явно, либо открывайте тоже контекстным менеджером.